# Prove that there exists an $n\times n$ matrix $B$ with real entries such that $B^2=A.$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ matrix with real entries such that $(A−I)^m=0$ for some $m\geq1$. Prove that there exists an $n\times n$ matrix $B$ with real entries such that $B^2=A.$

I have tried like this: Let $A=I+N$. Then $N^m=0$. Hence all eigenvalues of $A$ are $1$. From this how I can proceed?

Answer (score 2):

You have $A=I+N$. Consider
$$L=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}n N^n.$$
This is really a finite sum. It's a logarithm of $A$:
$$A=I+N=\exp(L)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{n!}L^n,$$
again a finite sum. Now let
$$B=\exp(L/2)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{2^n n!}L^n,$$
(yet again a finite sum).

Comment: A similar effect can be achieved by plugging $N$ into the Maclaurin series for $\sqrt{1 + x}$.

Answer (score 0):

The binomial series $(1+x)^{1/2}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{1/2}{k}x^k$ gives the square root of $1+x$ if $-1<x<1$. Substituting the matrix $N$ for $x$ is possible, since $N^i=0$ for all $i\geq m$. Take the resulting expression as $B$.